# Opengl Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw

I making an OpenGL video game using GLFW version 2. I am getting an error I do not understand

The following code is:

```
//
//  GameWindow.cpp
//  RocketGame
//
//  Created by Vaibhav Malhotra on 12/5/17.
//  Copyright © 2017 Vaibhav Malhotra. All rights reserved.
//

#include "GameWindow.hpp"

typedef struct
{
    GLfloat positionCoordinates[3];
    GLfloat textureCoordinates[2];
} vertexData;

#define Square_Size 100

vertexData vertices[] = {
    {{0.0f,0.0f,0.0f}, {0.0f,0.0f}},
    {{Square_Size,0.0f,0.0f},{1.0f,0.0f}},
    {{Square_Size,Square_Size,0.0f},{1.0f,1.0f}},
    {{0.0f,Square_Size,0.0f},{0.0f,1.0f}}
};

void GameWindow::setRunning(bool newRunning)
{
    _running = newRunning;
}

bool GameWindow::getRunning()
{
    return _running;
}

GLuint GameWindow::loadAndBufferImage(const char *filename)
{
    GLFWimage imageData;
    glfwReadImage(filename, &imageData, NULL);
    GLuint textureBufferID;
    glGenTextures(1, &textureBufferID);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureBufferID);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, imageData.Width, imageData.Height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, imageData.Data);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

    glfwFreeImage(&imageData);

    return textureBufferID;    
}

GameWindow::GameWindow(bool running):_running(running),_height(800),_width(800*16/9),_vertexBufferID(0)
{        
    glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    glViewport(0.0f, 0.0f, _width, _height);

    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    gluOrtho2D(0, _width, 0, _height);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

    glGenBuffers(1, &_vertexBufferID);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vertexBufferID);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(vertexData), (GLvoid *) offsetof(vertexData, positionCoordinates));

    glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(vertexData), (GLvoid *) offsetof(vertexData, textureCoordinates));

    _textureBufferID = loadAndBufferImage("rocket.tga");    
}

void GameWindow::render()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    //glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, 4);

    glfwSwapBuffers();        
}

void GameWindow::update()
{

}
```

Under the render function the code `glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, 4);` is returning a runtime error:

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0).

For output I am just getting a black screen.

Why is this error is coming for me?

Comment: Edit in a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Under the render function the code glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, 4); is returning a runtime error Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0).

A memory access violation on `glDrawArrays` generally hints at some sort of problem with VBOs or similar storage objects.

From what I can tell, there are three issues with your code:

- You are only calling `glEnableClientState` and its corresponding `gl*Pointer` calls once, when they need to be called every frame before `glDrawArrays`. If you'd like to only call them once, look into [Vertex Array Objects (VAOs)](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_Array_Object%20%22Vertex%20Array%20Objects%20(VAOs)), although these are only available since OpenGL 3. Bear in mind, that when you move the `glEnableClientState` calls, you will have to ensure that your buffer is bound again with `glBindBuffer`.
- Each client state has a corresponding `gl*Pointer` call. You correctly use `glVertexPointer` for `GL_VERTEX_ARRAY`, but for `GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY`, you need `glTexCoordPointer`.
- Your `glEnableClientState` calls are missing their corresponding `glDisableClientState` calls, which need to be called in reverse order of the enabling calls, after your `glDrawArrays` call.

---

Just as a side note, the GLU library is deprecated. Your `gluOrtho2D` call appears to be the only instance where you depend on it, and it can be easily replaced with:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glOrtho(0, _width, 0, _height, -1.0f, 1.0f);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an exception in `glDrawArrays` because it tries to read memory at address 0, which is what your code actually specifies.

GL's texture coordinate array pointer is initializez to `NULL` and no VBO. Since you use legacy GL, this will be interpreted as a client memory address. Now you enable `GL_TEXCOORD_ARRAY` but never actually set `glTexCoordPointer`, so it stays `NULL`:

```
glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(vertexData), (GLvoid *) offsetof(vertexData, textureCoordinates));
```

The quick solution is of course to not overwrite your vertex array pointer state by having it point to the the texture coords, but to specify the texcoord array pointer via `glTexCoordPointer`.

The *real* solution is to give up on legacy GL which is deprecated0 since a decade by now, and switch to "modern" OpenGL using a GL 3.2 core profile or above.